# The below SQL Query is taking more time and what are all the way to improve the performance?

Tags: sql

The below query is taking a lot of time, all the columns are indexed.

What are all the way to optimize it?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CAST(CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_ID AS VARCHAR (40))) 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM CORNER_ATTITUDE 
     WHERE OWNER_ID = '100' 
       AND CORNER_ATTITUDE_ID NOT IN (SELECT LEGAL_ID 
                                      FROM CAPTAIN_LOGIC 
                                      WHERE LEGAL_ID != '12345678' 
                                        AND OWNER_ID = '100')) CA 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   CORNER_ATTITUDE_MEMBER CAC ON (CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_ID = CAC.CORNER_ATTITUDE_ID) 
JOIN  
    (SELECT * 
     FROM MEMBER 
     WHERE MEMBER_ROLE_ID = 'MEMBER') C ON (CAC.MEMBER_FESTIVEL_ID = C.MEMBER_FESTIVEL_ID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    VINAYAN P ON (C.MEMBER_FESTIVEL_ID = P.VINAYAN_FESTIVEL_ID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    VINAYAN_NAME PN ON (P.VINAYAN_FESTIVEL_ID = PN.VINAYAN_FESTIVEL_ID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DRA_SERVER OC ON CAST (ca.STAR_0_Numer AS NVARCHAR2 (40)) = OC.SERVER_PID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT CORNER_ATTITUDE_ID, PROVIDE_ID 
     FROM STORED_PROVIDE 
     WHERE PROVIDE_ORIGIN_TYPE_CD = 'PROVIDE_ORIGIN_TYPE_DECISION_SERVICE') CF ON (CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_ID = CF.CORNER_ATTITUDE_ID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    STORED_DETAIL CD ON CD.PROVIDE_ID = CF.PROVIDE_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    STORED_APPL_PRODUCT CAP ON CAP.STORED_DETAIL_ID = CD.STORED_DETAIL_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    PRODUCT_TYPE PT ON PT.PRODUCT_TYPE_CD = CAP.PRODUCT_TYPE_CD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DRA O ON O.GREEN_FESTIVEL_ID = OC.SERVER_FESTIVEL_ID 
WHERE  
    (CA.STAR_0_STRG = 'TRUE' 
     AND CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_STATUS_CD <> 'A' 
     AND CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_STATUS_CD <> 'B' 
     AND CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_STATUS_CD <> 'C' 
     AND CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_STATUS_CD <> 'D' 
     AND CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_STATUS_CD <> 'E' 
     AND CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_STATUS_CD <> 'F' 
     AND CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_STATUS_CD <> 'G' 
     AND CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_STATUS_CD <> 'H' 
     AND CD.BORROW_USING_TXT <> 'I' 
     AND CD.BORROW_USING_TXT <> 'J' 
     AND CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_STATUS_CD <> 'K' 
     AND CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_STATUS_CD <> 'L' 
     AND CD.BORROW_USING_TXT <> 'M' 
     AND CD.BORROW_USING_TXT <> 'N' 
     AND CD.BORROW_USING_TXT <> 'O' 
     AND CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_STATUS_CD <> 'P' 
     AND CD.BORROW_USING_TXT <> 'Q') 
    AND OC.SERVER_XID IN (400 Integer values);
```

Comment: format your sql code,make it readable, add more information and tag it correctly, as you have `sql-server` and `oracle`, pick one.

Comment: Low hanging fruit for performance improvement. Don't use select *, only select the columns you actually need. Your where predicates are nonSARGable. More than anything else you need to organize and format this query. Your aliases make me want to take out my eyeballs and pop them. Aliases should provide some indication of what table they represent. Yours seem to be random characters which have nothing to do with the name of the table. You are inconsistent with inequality checks. In some places != and others <>.

Comment: To truly provide any tangible benefit you need to decide which DBMS you are using. Then you need to provide ddl (including indexes) for the tables. Just saying all columns are indexed is usually an indication that the indexing strategy is not a good one.

Comment: @SeanLange `Your aliases make me want to take out my eyeballs and pop them.`  LOL!!!

Comment: If I move the != and <> means I shoudl have to do = with large number of data

Comment: Normal (I.e. B-tree indexes) cannot work on <> condition. Consider Bitmap indexes. These columns also seem to have low cardinality.

Comment: No. I meant you are using inequality and you are inconsistent in your coding style. You should pick ONE of the ways to represent not equal and stick with it for the whole query. Given the large number of inequality checks you might be better to create a temp table and left join it. But of course this depends on which DBMS you are using.

Comment: I removed the DBMS specific tags. Feel free to add back the one that you are actually using.

Comment: The equjoin will be helpful instead of Outer Join?

Comment: What are you actually counting? Trusting to column names, most relations seem n:m. There are three join chains: 1. ca->cac->c->p->pn, 2. ca->cf->cd->cap->pt, 3. ca->oc->o. I surmise every chain can result in several rows per ca. So lets's say for a ca you get 5 pn, 6 pt, 3 o, which you count as 5 x 6 x 3= 90. What can this number possibly mean to you?

Comment: Once more the question: what is your DBMS? And then please tell us the unique columns per table, so we see which relations are 1:n and which are m:n.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to read the query without formatting. However, a few things to think about:

- Since `CA.STAR_0_STRG` seems to be boolean, you don't need to use a `VARCHAR`
- Do you really need all of those conditions in your `WHERE`? Can you reduce or simplify them? I see eleven conditions on the same field, like in `CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_STATUS_CD <> 'K' AND CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_STATUS_CD <> 'L'`.
- (Most important) Can you move some of the logic from the condition of your final `WHERE` to predicates in some of the many `JOIN`s that you're doing? It would help you a lot if you could reduce the amount of data that you're actually joining.

Comment: Yes, I need to use all the conditions in the where, Would it be helpful If I move those to inside of NOT IN() ?

Comment: It would certainly make it more readable. However, your query would likely be more performant if you moved those conditions to the `WHERE` here:

Comment: ` SELECT COUNT (CAST (CA.CORNER_ATTITUDE_ID AS VARCHAR (40))) 
FROM (SELECT * FROM CORNER_ATTITUDE 
      WHERE...` Since presently you're `JOIN`ing a bunch of data that you later discard. Along those same lines, you're using `SELECT *` when you only need some columns and could specifically `SELECT` those columns.

Comment: I have moved the CA.STAR_0_STRG = 'TRUE' to the top select and Now little bit reduced the time.

But I am mainly seeing Is there any possibilities to reduce the time in the where conditions in the bottom lines.

(SELECT * FROM CORNER_ATTITUDE 
      WHERE CA.STAR_0_STRG = 'TRUE' AND OWNER_ID = '100' AND CORNER_ATTITUDE_ID 
      NOT IN (SELECT LEGAL_ID 
              FROM CAPTAIN_LOGIC WHERE LEGAL_ID != '12345678' 
              AND OWNER_ID = '100'))